# How can I write a program that transforms letters to upper or lower case depending on command line arguments?

Tags: c

I was writing this code for a C program that transforms letters to lower case when called as:

```
./arg lower
```

and transforms them to upper case when invoked as:

```
./arg upper
```

Here is the code which I wrote, kindly help me out:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    char c;
    for(i=1;i<argc;++i)
    {

        if(*(argv+i)=="lower")
        {
             while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
                 {
                      c=tolower(c);
                      putchar(c);
                 }
        }
        if(*(argv+i)=="upper")
        {
            while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
                 {
                      c=toupper(c);
                      putchar(c);
                 }                    
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can see 2 things wrong with this question. __1__: It isn't a real question. For the life of me, I can't figure out _what_ you want to ask and why you want it. __2__: __Is my c code correct?__ Ask your teacher.

Comment: @Pranav: The code is not very long, and there is something clearly wrong with it. It's not a very well-worded question, but it isn't a horrible first question either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do string comparisons like that in C, you need to use `strcmp(3)`.

Better yet, use `strncmp(3)` and specify the size of your buffer.

Finally, for array access, you could use `argv[i]` instead of `*(argv+i)`. The meaning is the same, but the first version is much more readable.

So, you'd want something like:

```
if (0 == strncmp(argv[i], "lower", 6)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the `strcmp()` function to compare strings.

Answer (score 2):

When doing `*(argv+i)=="lower"` you are actually comparing the pointer to such c-strings. You need to use `strcmp` to see if the content of such strings are equal, in which case `strcmp`  returns zero.

Answer (score 1):

`fgetc` returns an int, not a char. If you truncate it you'll be ok this time, but will suffer horrible torments when working with binary data.

Comment: I assume you meant `getchar(3)`? Note that the problem here is that `getchar(3)` returns an `unsigned char` cast into an `int`, and that if one does the comparison the way the code in question does it you can confuse the legitimate character `0xFF` and `EOF`. Good catch!